# Is it possible to detach event listeners?

Tags: plugin-development, events

I've got an event listener hooked up like this:

```
craft()->on('elements.populateElement', array($this, 'onPopulateElements'));
```

Is it possible to detach/deregister the listener? E.g. something like this (this doesn't work, but to illustrate):

```
craft()->off('elements.populateElement', array($this, 'onPopulateElements'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible currently, but there's [a feature request](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1118).

Answer (score 0):

Completely untested, and not sure if this will work with events registered with [on](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/web/WebApp#on-detail), instead of the traditional Yii method, but try either:

```
craft()->detachEventHandler('elements.onPopulateElements', array($this, 'elements.onPopulateElements'));
```

or:

```
craft()->detachEventHandler('onPopulateElements', array($this, 'onPopulateElements'));
```

If neither of those work, then we'd need to add a custom `off` that takes into account the `componentName.event` event syntax that `on` users.

Comment: Thanks @Brad – unfortunately I wasn't able to make either of those work. The use case is that I only want/need the `elements.onPopulateElement` event handler to trigger one time (the event fires several times for most requests), so I figured the clean thing would be to detach the listener when the event fires the first time. I can put a flag in the event handler so no biggie, but an `off` method would be nice – I'll put up a feature request :)

Comment: Awesome... I was going to suggest a feature request, then. :)